# Merge two arrays with same keys

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge the following arrays:

```
$songs = array(
    [0] => 001. Daddy&#039;s Groove Feat Mindshake - Surrender (Extended Mix).mp3
    [1] => 002. Haddaway - What Is Love (Project 46 Remix).mp3
    [2] => 003. Black Van - Fen Fires.mp3
    [3] => 004. Giorno - The Way (Radio Edit).mp3
    [4] => 005. Jack &amp; Joy Vs Menini &amp; Viani Ft Greg Stainer - #Aahm (Gran Hotel Mix).mp3
    [5] => 006. Almyron - Tonight (Radio Edit).mp3
    [6] => 007. Caminita Feat. Jan Peter - Tonite (Original Mix).mp3
    [7] => 008. Lucas Nord, Urban Cone, John Dahlback - We Were Gods (Original Mix).mp3
    [8] => 009. Luca Cassani - Greed (Extended Mix).mp3
    [9] => 010. Bakermat - Uitzicht.mp3
    [10] => 011. Freaky Behaviour - Dream Topping.mp3
)

$sizes = array(
    [0] => 14.1 MB
    [1] => 13.81 MB
    [2] => 12.5 MB
    [3] => 7.58 MB
    [4] => 14.15 MB
    [5] => 7.76 MB
    [6] => 10.85 MB
    [7] => 14.02 MB
    [8] => 12.66 MB
    [9] => 11.86 MB
    [10] => 17.57 MB
);
```

To look like this:

```
$result = array(
    [0] => array(
        name => 001. Daddy&#039;s Groove Feat Mindshake - Surrender (Extended Mix).mp3
        size => 14.1 MB
    )
    [1] => array(
        name => 002. Haddaway - What Is Love (Project 46 Remix).mp3
        size => 13.81 MB
    )
    ...
);
```

I've tried `array_merge` and `array_combine` but I couldn't do it. I'm using PHP `5.5`. The keys in the `$result` are not important to be the same as `$songs` and `$sizes`. I hope it's not very difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$result = array_map(function ($song, $size) {
    return ['song' => $song, 'size' => $size];
}, $songs, $sizes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$songs` and `$sizes` always have the same length,

```
$result = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($songs);$i++) {
    $result[] = array(
        'name'=>$songs[i],
        'size'=>$sizes[i]
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've used the other example, but also voted for yours! :-)